# Ruby on Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in Ruby on Rails and don't know much about Ruby and Ruby on Rails styles. I started with authorization with omniauth. I want to sign in only with external services accounts. Next step will be authorization with multiple accounts.

But now I have this a bit ugly code, that creates new or returns old user when I go to /auth/twitter, for example. Can you tell me how to make it more ruby?

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authentications

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"])
    authentication.nil? ? create_with_omniauth(auth) : authentication.user
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    @user = User.new
    @user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
    @user.save

    @user.authentications.create_with_omniauth(auth, @user.id)
    @user
  end
end
```

authentication.rb

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth, user_id)
    @authentication = Authentication.new
    @authentication.user_id = user_id
    @authentication.provider = auth[:provider]
    @authentication.uid = auth[:uid]
    @authentication.save
  end
end
```

authentication_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = Authentication.all
  end

  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "signed in"
  end

  def destroy
    @authentication = Authentication.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed authentication."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do to make it more rails-y is to assign the members of a new object at creation time using the symbols of those members:

```
def self.create_with_omniauth(auth, user_id)
   @authentication = Authentication.create(:user_id  => user_id, 
                                           :provider => auth[:provider],
                                           :uid      => auth[:uid])
end
```

You will want to use the create call so that Rails will write to the DB, This way you don't have to call the save function after you set the members to the values you want.

Also, I know you are trying to roll your own auth library, but you might want to look into the auth libraries that are out there such as AuthLogic.

Comment: Auth libraries has too much unnecessary functionality like, for example, standard email-password authentication. I want just simple authorization only throw external services and I don't think that it's too complicated task even for newbee

Comment: No doubt, just didn't know if you knew about them.